# Mapping: convert lan and lon to X Y

Tags: c#, html, json, esri

```
for(var i = 0; i < jsonIncident.length; i++)
{
    var x = jsonIncident[i].Latitude        
    var y = jsonIncident[i].Longitude 

    //I can only retreive lat and lon for the image position
    //However to add an image i need it to be in x and y format.


    var type = jsonIncident[i].IncidentType
    var time = jsonIncident[i].MyDate
    var loc = jsonIncident[i].MyDate
    var desc = jsonIncident[i].Description
    var image

    //This where you add the image

    var incident = new esri.Graphic({ "geometry": { "x": x, "y": y,
        "spatialReference": { "wkid": 3414 }
        }, "attributes": { "Title": type,
        "Time": time, "Location": loc, "Description": desc, } });

        incident.setSymbol(image);
        incident.setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);
        map.graphics.add(incident);

}

map.infoWindow.resize(320, 130);
```

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, but can you explain what you mean by `convert lan and lon to X Y`

Comment: becuase the part where you add the image, it can only take in X any Y format. However, what im retrieving is in lat and lon format(:

Comment: that really didn't answer the question.  That explanation is just restating converting lat/lon to X Y.  Are your latitude and longitude in degrees/minutes/seconds, or decimal degrees, or some other data type?  And I'm not familiar with the ESRI API.  What are X and Y?  Are the integers?  doubles?  You need to provide more detail if we are going to be able to help you.

Comment: This is a example of lat and lon

Comment: "Latitude":1.2989858745434002,"Longitude":103.84342613728055

Comment: To add an image it got to be in x and y format. They are coordinates on the map.

Comment: but the point I am trying to make are X and Y are not a format, they are just parameters in a constructor for a specific object in a 3rd party API. So you need to explain what you are trying to convert Latitude and Longitude too.  Are X and Y just double?  If so then there is no conversion needed.  Latitude is Y and Longitude is X

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can create a graphic using either projected or geographic coordinate systems.  See http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/help/jshelp_start.htm#jshelp/inside_graphics.htm